# In clause in Select statement of SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql

I have an SQL Server Query:

`select *from table1 where column in ('list of values')`

When I execute this, I get all the details, however, when I do this:

`select *from table1 where column in ('list of values') and date_of_req='2011-03-15'`

I get an empty table. All the column headings are there, but with no data. How to overcome this? I basically want to match all of those values in the IN clause and the date and display only that data.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure there are any records where `date_of_req='2011-03-15`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a time part as well. Ensure you are getting the date part out of date_of_req.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly! :) God! I'm such a dunderhead!

Comment: Note though that 'extracting the date part out'  usually results in an un-SARG-able expression (ie. an index on `date_of_req` would be ignored).

Comment: You had! I marked even Remus' answer and I guess it changed.. Sorry :(

Comment: Need further help Adam.. I need to retrieve the previous date using the current date through `getdate()` or something in the following format: `yyyy-mm-dd` and then equate that to a column in my table. I got the previous date using `datediff`, but could not get it in the format I want, and hence can't equate it to the column. Been trying out different stuff, but can't get it to work. Any help?

Comment: You are probably looking for dateadd. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: I got a dateadd function that retrieves the previous date and a convert that gets that date in yyyymmdd format. What I want is to get it in yyyy-mm-dd format and use that in a query. I've tried all sorts of combinations and nothing's working out. :(

Comment: If I use: `SELECT DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, GETDATE()), -1)`, I get: **2011-03-14 00:00:00.000**.  If I use `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, GETDATE()), -1),111)`, I get: **2011/03/14**. I want **2011-03-14** and to compare this in a query. How?

Answer (score 4):

DATETIME likely has a time part too. Also, get in the habit of using the language insensitive datetime literal form (`'YYYYMMDD'`) Try:

```
select *from table1 where column in ('list of values') 
and date_of_req=>'20110315'
and date_of_req < '20110316';
```

Answer (score 0):

`date_of_req` have time part as well. So you can compare your date part of your column with below query

```
select * 
from table1 
where column in ('list of values') 
  and CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), date_of_req, 111) = '2011-03-15'
```